# The file reference for "Firebase.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have this issue and cannot find more relevant information about it.
The whole message says:

> xcodebuild[41239:2858194] warning:  The file reference for
>   "Firebase.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files"
>   and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
>   membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in
>   targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file
>   in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.

So far I tried:

- clean pod cache
- delete the Podfile.lock
- delete  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
- deintegrate the pod
- delete ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
- flutter clean

Nothing changed. The problem persists.

My Podfile is:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_modular_headers!

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me with this?

PD. I have this warning:

> /Users/some/path/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+6/ios/Classes/FirebaseCorePlugin.m:8:9:
>   fatal error: 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found
>       #import 
>               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>       note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

... and this one too:

> This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 12.4
>   (16G77), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

But since I'm using the iPhone simulator and not the real device the last one is somehow irrelevant.

Edit: Some more info that might help.
When I run pod update I get this:
Downloading dependencies

> Installing Firebase 2.5.1
>   Installing Firebase 6.5.0 (was 2.5.1)

There are clearly 2 versions of Firebase installed, but I have no idea why this happens.
My pubspec.yaml dependencies are:

```
dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6

  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+10

  firebase_database: ^3.0.4

  http: ^0.12.0+2

  google_sign_in: ^4.0.4

  provider: ^3.0.0+1

  flutter_geofire: ^0.0.4

  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.19+2

  location: ^2.3.5
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Comment: nope, I've started a clean project, adding the packages one by one and everything was fine so far 'till implemented flutter_facebook_login, then I had to update the pod and do some more stuff, but right now the project is like a rocket :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe solved your problem:

Go to ios/ folder
run:

```
pod outdated
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to you iOS/.symlinks folder and remove firebase plugin (may not exist)
2. flutter clean
3. Backup your Podfile
4. Delete Podfile.lock
5. Delete Pods folder
6. Delete Podfile
7. In terminal: pod init (inside the iOS folder)
8. In terminal: pod install
9. Copy your podfile contents from the backup
10. In terminal: pod init
11. In terminal: pod install
12. In terminal: flutter run or just flutter build iOS (cd to pubspec.yaml is)